# QGIS - use atlas attribute with 'Like' command

Tags: qgis, atlas

Does anyone know how to use the new get Attribute function in conjunction with the "Like" command?

I have a table with an Attribute "Sub_Region" and want to show the features that match the atlas feature of the same name...

The syntax below works for "="
"Sub_Region" = attribute($atlasfeature, 'Region_Name')

However, some of my precincts cover two regions, so the attribute might be 'Central, Western'. I can manually show only those of interest by selecting: 
"Sub_Region" like '%Western%' .... however I want to inset the Attribute function so that I don't have to manually change the query as I export the atlas but can't work out the correct syntax...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
  "Sub_Region" like '%' || attribute($atlasfeature, 'Region_Name') || '%'
```

Comment: perfect! thanks. I knew it would be obvious as soon as I got it...